# Fetching, modifying, and deleting lines in CodeIgniter language files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a website that is a business directory.  These businesses are grouped into categories, which are stored in the database.  My issue right now is that this website is going to be multilingual and the names of the categories need to be stored in language files.  I can simply add a column to the categories table called "language_index" and then call it like this...

```
foreach($query_categories->result_array() as $cat){

     $title = $this->lang->line($cat['language_index']);

}
```

But the bigger issue is modifying the language file to change, add, or delete a certain line if a category is added, modified, or deleted in the database. In my form to create categories, I can loop through all the languages and then add a form field for each language that would save a different category name to each language file... for example:

```
<input type="text" name="english_cat_title">
<input type="text" name="filipino_cat_title">
```

But again, I would need to be able to easily modify the category_names language file.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I think :

You store your categories like that :

```
id_category  |  lang  |  name
------------------------------
          1  |    en  |  Cat
          1  |    fr  |  Chat
       ....
```

You can make a primary key id_category + lang.

Then you get your categories by langage :

```
$category = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('lang' => $user_lang))->row();
```

And you add the result to global langage :

```
$category_lang['category_name'] = $category->name;
$this->lang->language = array_merge($this->lang->language, $category_lang);

echo $this->lang('category_name');
```

You can adapt of course if you have several rows or whatever.